# Problem with making a database on base of EER

Tags: mysql

I want to make a database based on my EER, but if I use Forward Engineering it always throws the same error.

Executing SQL script in server:

```
> ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
> syntax to use near ') ENGINE = InnoDB' at line 8
```

SQL Code:

---

```
-- Table `gip`.`Groepen`
-- -----------------------------------------------------

   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gip`.`Groepen` (
  `idGroepen` INT NOT NULL,
  `Groepnaam` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`idGroepen`),
   UNIQUE INDEX `Groepnaam_UNIQUE` (`Groepnaam` ASC) VISIBLE)
   ENGINE = InnoDB
```

SQL script execution finished: statements: 6 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: The first step to getting help on this site is to _format_ your question properly.  Please add four or more spaces to each line which you intend to be code.

Comment: Perhaps visible is not supported by your version of mysql

Comment: I just installed it today so I think it is.

Comment: So... what version is that?

Comment: It's 8.0 CE version

Answer (score 0):

I think VISIBLE is added after MySQL server version > 8.0 and you are using less than that.

Moreover, according to https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92269, VISIBLE is default value. You can remove it.